# I want to replace an element in a QString - QT - C++

Tags: c++, qt, replace, qstring

I have following problem:
I saved in a QString an XMLStart.

```
QString f = "<class=\"go\">\n"
            "<number>2</number>\n"
            "<column>3</column>\n"
            "<row>4</row>";
```

I want to change for example the value of row with 7 in this String by for example using replace or something like that.

```
f.replace();
```

How can i achive that ? Is that possible?

Regards

Comment: ***Is that possible?*** I would expect the answer is yes.

Comment: That depends on what exactly you want to achieve.
`f.replace("<row>4</column>", "<row>7</row>");` should do what you are requesting for this particular case.

But as soon as the value changes, the code becomes useless.

Comment: If its always the 7th row there could be different approaches. One being convert to a QStringList using `QString::split('\n');` then process the seventh item of the QStringList then `QStringlist::join('\n');` this probably is not the most performant code but if you don't need to do it a thousand times it may be good enough. You could also use `QString::indexOf('\n',pos)' in a loop to find the 7th and 8th row indices and do your replacement between the two.

Comment: Does your xml always have the same structure or not?

Comment: Also Qt has xml support. Maybe you can use that instead.

Comment: is this a typo? ***<row>4</column>*** or is the file broken?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XML in Qt and I'm sure that there is a more elegant way that hopefully someone will post after me, but this is an easy way to do your replacement.

*Of course you'll have to provide the string values in a better way...*

```
QString xml = "<class=\"go\">\n"
              "<number>2</number>\n"
              "<column>3</column>\n"
              "<row>4</row>";
QString tag = "row";
QString val = "7";

QByteArray exp("<%1>%2</%1>");
QString rex = QString(exp).arg(tag, ".*");
QString rep = QString(exp).arg(tag, val);

xml.replace(QRegExp(rex), rep);
```